# Multiple GORM ValidationException after import from excel file

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I work on a bug. I have a excel file that is imported into the application.
The file contains information for the core domain object (Zoo, see below). Every row has two cells, string value for the name and int value for the number of animals.

If i have an invalid field inside this excel file, it will show an error msg like *"Error on column X on cell Y.  Value is "someValue" invalid"*. Let's assume we have an excel file with 250 rows. If we have an invalid field error on row 200, **every row that comes after it will throw the following error**

```
Validation error whilst flushing entity [com.rolotec.ost.Zoo]:
- Field error in object 'com.rolotec.ost.Zoo' on field 'ceo': rejected value [null]
```

If i look in the DB the object isn't null on ceo field.

Here the domain objects.

```
class Zoo{   
  String name;
  int animalsInTheZoo;
  CEO ceo;
  hasMany=[ zooEnclosures : ZooEnclosures]
  constraints=[//some constraints]   
}

class CEO{
  Date ceoTillDate;
  Person person;
  constraints=[//some constraints]    
}

class Person{    
  String name;
  int age;
  constraints=[//some constraints]  
}
```

Here is the service for the import

```
class ImportService{

importExcel(){

    String errorMsg="";

    Zoo.withTransaction { status->   
        try{

            //some other operations 
            for(int rowNum = excelFile.firstRow; rowNum<=excelFile.lastRow; rowNum++) {  
            try {
                importRow(row);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //doSomething
            }
           } //end for-loop
            if (errorMsg != "") {
                status.setRollback();
            }     
        } catch(Exception e){
            //doSomething with e
            status.setRollback();               
        }

    }           
}

importRow(Row row){    
    String name = row.getCell(1).stringCellValue;
    Zoo.findAllByName(name).each{    
        try{    
            //reads every cell in Excel data and validates the field
            it.save() //error occures here in the validation    
        } catch(Exception e){
            //doSomething with e
        }
    }
}
```

If i inspect the object, it will have a value for it.ceo.name but the rest will be null inside it.ceo. Also will be the it.ceo.person = null. In the DB there are all values for the attributes.

**EDIT:** If there are no invalid fields inside the excel file, there are no ValidationException. Everything will be imported fine.

**EDIT 2:** Added the for-loop inside the importExcel() method.

Comment: why do you have catch(Exception) twice, but only rollback on the first one?

Comment: @tim_yates i corrected it. It will make a rollback if the errorMsgs isnt empty and if an exception will be thrown by the first try-block. If your question is still the same, i can't answer you because we took the project from the client and that's what i found

Comment: why don't you use `.withNewTransaction()` for every separated row from your excel? they will be threated independently.

Comment: @Michal_Szulc would be a next step, but even if i change it now the same errors occure. I make an invalid field on the Zoo.name in the first row in excel and all rows afterwards will throw an ValidationExceptioni on Zoo.name. If i inspect the object, there will be a String inside the name attribute but still throw the error

Comment: Could you provide PoC project with example excel file with few rows which could replicate the issue?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc we found the bug with a Senior Engineer. I made an edit on the code, where i added the for-loop inside the transaction. We fixed it and the bug was gone. I'll post the answer below with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that inside the `Zoo.withTransaction` closure was a for-loop which looped through all the rows inside the excel file. For the solution, we moved the `.withTransaction` inside the for-loop and the problem was gone.

Code in ImportService looks now like this:

```
  importExcel(){

   String errorMsg="";
   //some operations
   for(int rowNum = excelFile.firstRow; rowNum<=excelFile.lastRow; rowNum++){
      Zoo.withTransaction{status -> 
       //some operations
       try{
        importRow(row)
       } 
      catch(Exception e){
          //do something with exception
          status.setRollbackOnly()
       }
      }
     }

   }
```